# Is there a formula for the number of "faces"/boundaries of an hypercube defined by a multidimensional grid?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, numerical-methods, discrete-optimization

Consider a D dimensional grid, $ X =  X_{1} \times X_{2} \times ... \times X_{D} $.

Denote the size of $X_{j}$ with $| X_{j} |$.

What is the  formula for the number of "faces"/boundaries of an hypercube defined by a multidimensional grid?

Comment: Take away the outer points in each dimension and multiply the remaining amounts. Points in faces are still points on the boundary.

Comment: how about the number of faces

Comment: That is just the number of faces of an hypercube. For each dimension you have 3 choices, left, middle, right. For a face not all choices can be middle. Or $\binom Dk 2^k$ for faces of co-dimension $k=1,2,...,D$.